# How to redirect parent page from iframe popup?

Tags: php

So I have a page where when user click on login button, it will open up an iframe popup with a login form. So, if the user submitted the correct username/password, it will redirect the parent page to let say `Main.php`. However, I wasn't able to achieve this as it keeps on redirecting it in the iframe popup. How do I achieve this? I'm fairly new to php so please clarify your answer.

Here's the code snippet that processes the login. Tell me if you need more. Thank you.

```
<?php
include '../Initialization.php';

if (empty ($_POST) === false) {

    $username = $_POST ['username'];
    $password = $_POST ['password'];

    if (empty ($username) === true || empty ($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password!';
    } else if (user_exists ($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find the username you entered. Have you registered?';
    } else if (user_active ($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account!';
    } else {
        $login = login($username, $password);
        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect!';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            header("Refresh:0; url=../../Main.php"); //Am I doing anything wrong here? 
            exit();
        }
    }

    print_r ($errors);
}
?>
```

The link that will open up the iframe :

```
<a class='iframe' href="Login.php" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFF">LET'S GO</a
```

The login form :

```
    <form action = "Core/System/LoginProcess.php" method="post">
      <p>
        <input name="username" type="text" class="textBox" id="username2" placeholder = "Username" onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);"/>
          <br />
          <br />
        <input name="password" type="password" class="textBox" id="password" placeholder = "Password" />
</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>
        <input name="Login" type="submit" class="loginButton" id="Login" value="Login" />
      </p>
      </form>
```

Comment: it is better, if you add up some html here, that you worked on..

Comment: @ameenulla0007 I have updated the post with HTML part that I think related to this problem or you need anything more?

Comment: does your `Login.php` opens in a new window?

Comment: @ameenulla0007 nope, it open as an iframe popup which is basically act as overlay.

Comment: there is again a question in this :) overlay window or overlay Modal?

Comment: @ameenulla0007 I'm sorry but what is the difference between those two? Did a quick search on google, but It looks basically the same. The iframe popup is opened in the parent windows, darkens the background, and can be close anytime if user click anywhere outside the frame, or the close button. Does this help?

Comment: Modal pop-up is within the current HTML, but pop-up window opens a new window with its own HTML..

Comment: @ameenulla0007 oh. I think it's a popup window as I load the `Login.php` html externally into an iframe overlay to display it on my homepage. Is it not possible? Since this question doesn't even have a single answer yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107449/discussion-between-ameenulla0007-and-nazhirin-imran).